# Where to add Mailchimp Subscriber Popup code in magento

Tags: layout, javascript, cms, magento-1.9.2.1, popup

I apologize if this question has been posted before, but I checked all over google and could not find anything.

I am trying to add the Mailchimp subscriber popup to my homepage, but cannot figure out where to place the code. The following code is provided by Mailchimp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us13.list-manage.com","uuid":"5a1a0fd7515829aea469xxxxx","lid":"3ce6dxxxxx"}) })</script>
```

The problem I am having with this code is that anywhere I place it, it will not display in the frontend. I have tried adding the code to template/page/html/head.phtml, tried adding it directly to the content section of the homepage cms page, tried adding the code in the page layout section for the homepage cms page using a xml reference block i found in another post, and i have tried to add the code under system/configuration/general/design/HTML Head in Miscellaneous Scripts.

However, I have not had any success at all. It is my understanding that the popup should be displayed after refreshing the homepage. If i use developer tools in google chrome, i can see the above code in the head section, but it is not doing anything.

I am using magento version 1.9.2.1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would turn the 'debug'  flag on, that help you narrow it down

Comment: have you got the solution for your question. Even I am having the same issues.